# Crash on launch after downgrade to iOS 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

I have a game released on the App Store for iOS 6.1, and I wanted to make it work for iOS 5. However, my application crashed on launch with iOS 5. I reverted it to iOS 6.1, but it still crashes! Any ideas? And no, I didn't make any other changes to the app. If you want any code, tell me in the comments. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check libraries , SDK which are used for different versions.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I'll test this when I get a chance!

Comment: Um, where are those located? I can see the SDK version, but not the libraries.  EDIT: Nevermind, I found the libs, but the app still crashes.

Comment: then you will have to debug your code and find where it is crashing.